# Proof: Between two distinct real numbers ther is a rational number.

Tags: real-analysis

I found this proof:

If $a<b$, there is a rational $\frac{p}{q}$ with q fixed, and p any integer.

Consider the set of numbers of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ with $q$ fixed, and $p$ any integer.
Assume that there are no such numbers between $a$ and $b$. Let $\frac{p}{q}$ be the number immediately before $a$. Then $\frac{p+1}{q}$ is the number immediately after $b$. We necessarily have

$$\frac{p+1}{q} - \frac{p}{q} \geq b - a \Leftarrow\Rightarrow \frac{1}{q} \geq b-a$$

If we choose q sufficiently large, then the above inequality is wrong. Then there is at least one rational number between $a$ and $b$.

For example:

I have $a=1$ and $b=3$, $\frac{p}{q}= \frac{1}{1}$ and  $\frac{p+1}{q}=\frac{1+1}{q}= \frac{2}{1} $ and $\frac{2}{2} \ngeq 3$.

How is it possible that this works for $a=1$ and $b=3$?

Comment: That statement is false. What if $a=\frac13$, $b=\frac23$, and $q=1$?

Comment: If $q=1$ and $p=1$ then $\frac{p}{q}= \frac{1}{1}=a$, and the next $p=2$ with the same $q$ works: $\frac{p}{q}= \frac{2}{1}=2$ is between $a=1$ and $b=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spirit of the proof is this: if you dilate the interval $[a,b]$ by a factor $q$ sufficiently large that $qb-qa>1$, then the interval will contain at least one integer $p$, and the fraction $\dfrac pq$ is a rational in $[a,b]$.

With $a=1,b=3,q=1$, the condition is fulfilled (we have the three rationals $\dfrac11,\dfrac21,\dfrac31$).

Comment: helped thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have changed the value of $q$ in your example. It should be $\frac{p+1}{q} = \frac{1+1}{1} = 2$ instead of 1. Apart from that mistake, the proof says "If we choose $q$ sufficiently large". Obviously $q=1$ is not large enough.

Comment: But $q=1$ *is* large enough in this case, $2/1$ is between $1$ and $3$.

Comment: But $\frac{p+1}{q}$ should be greater than 3, that's why isn't large enough.

Comment: It shouldn't, just the opposite. "If we choose $q$ sufficiently large, then the above inequality is wrong. Then there is at least one rational number between a and b". *When* $q$ is large enough we do not blow past $b$ when adding $1$ to $p$, and get an intermediate rational.